# Insert json data into MySQL database with slashdb rest api

Tags: mysql, json, rest, erlang, slashdb

I’m not able to insert  data into mysql database with slashdb rest.
I receive a post request from my iot service with json data in the body message, post request canes from this erlang pice of code:

```
    Method = post,
    URL = "http://xxxxxxx/api/v2/sensor_sql/_table/s1",
    Header = [{"X-DreamFactory-Api-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}],
    Type = "application/json",
    Body = MessageStr,
    HTTPOptions = [],
    Options = [],
    R = httpc:request(Method, {URL, Header, Type, Body},HTTPOptions, Options),
```

the body is like:

{"Temperature":22.7,"Humidity":99.9},"TempUnit":"C"}

and I need to use slashdb to insert these body's data into my database.
Which is the way to properly configure my sql statement in slashdb query to perform this task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I solved it by myself.
To insert a json data array into your mysql database you only need to specify your rest htlm address ( use "Data Discovery" in slashdb) and pass alle the json data in the body of your post request.
If you need to update more than one field, make your request against the resource endpoint (individual record), and send JSON object as payload. Here's how to update both the BillingPostalCode and the BillngCountry fields for the same record at the same time:

```
curl https://demo.slashdb.com/db/Chinook/Invoice/InvoiceId/1 -XPUT -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"BillingPostalCode": "456" "BillingCountry": "Germany"}'
```